# Websocket Pathparam Validation

Tags: java, websocket

I try to apply websockets at server side to receive information from different clients The websocket Endpoint uses a pathparam to identify the specific cleint.

```
ws://192.168.1.100:8080/listener/device_00001
```

And the end point class is:

```
@ServerEndpoint(
   value = "/listener/{deviceid}",
   configurator = WsConfig.class,
   subprotocols = {"abcProtocolv1", "abcProtocolv2"}
)
public class WsServer {

   @OnOpen
   public void onOpen(final Session session, @PathParam("deviceid") final String id) {
      //some handling method
   }

   @OnClose
   //some code here

   @OnMessage
   //some code here

}
```

The code is working well until this step and I can receive messages from different clients and identify devices based on pathparam.

However, I would like to send a 404 response to fail the upgrade handshake if the device id is invalid. The 404 response should be sent before @OnOpen and I have checked the configurator and there are only five functions included:

- getEndpointInstance
- getNegotiatedSubprotocol
- getNegotiatedExtensions
- checkOrigin
- modifyHandshake

All functions seem not able to handle validation before upgrade handshake but I cannot find any common approach.

Should I also apply @WebFilter? or is there any common approach in @ServerEndPoint?

Answer (score 1):

I try to handle the validation in `modifyHandshake` finally but it should not be a  common approach.

In `modifyHandshake`, the `@PathParam` variable can be found in `request.getParameterMap()`.

```
@Override
public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig sec, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
    String deviceId = request.getParameterMap().get("deviceid").get(0);
    if (isDeviceValid(deviceId)) {
       //Some code here and 101 is kept 
    } else {
       //Use java reflection to modify the http status and then clear the header 
       //The reflection code is depended on your Http Handler type
       response.getHeaders().clear()
    }
}
```